# Show that the average depth of a leaf in a binary tree with n vertices is $ \Omega(\log n)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $T$ be a tree with$n$ vertices, having height $h$. If there are any internal vertices in $T$ at levels less than $h — 1$ that do not have two children, take a leaf at level $h$ and move it to be such a missing child. This only lowers the average depth of a leaf in this tree, and since we are trying to prove a lower bound on the average depth, it suffices to prove the bound for the resulting tree. Repeat this process until there are no more internal vertices of this type. As a result, all the leaves are now at levels $h — 1$ and $h$. Now delete all vertices at level $h$. This changes the number of vertices by at most (one more than) a factor of two and so has no effect on a big-Omega estimate (it changes $\log n$ by at most 1). Now the tree is complete, and it has $2^{h-1}$ leaves, all at depth $h — 1$, where now $n = 2^{h-1}$. The desired estimate follows.
The statement above is the answer from the textbook,but I couldn't understand it. Is there anyone can give me a more explicit answer?

Comment: Can you be more precise about which parts you understand and which parts you don't?

Comment: **As a result, all the leaves are now at levels h—1 and h  ...... Now the tree is complete, ..... ** @Kimball

Answer (score 1):

We can  do much  better than  this lower bound  and compute  the exact
asymptotics.

**Remark.** I just realized I computed the average depth of the internal nodes and not the leaves. Correction TBA.

Note  that the  functional  equation for  binary  trees classified  by
height is
$$T(z, u) = 1 + uzT(uz, u)^2.$$

As we are interested in the average we need to compute
$$G(z) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} T(z, u)\right|_{u=1}.$$

We differentiate the functional equation, getting
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} T(z, u)
= z T(uz, u)^2
+ 2uz T(z, u) \left(z\frac{\partial}{\partial z} T(z, u)
+ \frac{\partial}{\partial u} T(z, u)\right).$$

Writing  $T(z)$  for the  solution  of  $T(z) =  1  +  z T(z)^2$,  the
generating function of the Catalan numbers
$$C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} {2n\choose n}$$
we set $u=1$ to obtain
$$G(z) = zT(z)^2 + 2z T(z) (z T'(z) + G(z))$$
which yields
$$G(z) = z\frac{T(z)^2+2z T(z) T'(z)}{1-2z T(z)}.$$

From the functional equation we have
$$T'(z) = T(z)^2 + 2z T(z) T'(z)$$
or $$T'(z) = \frac{T(z)^2}{1-2zT(z)}$$
so $G(z)$ becomes
$$G(z) = z\frac{T(z)^2+2z T(z)^3/(1-2zT(z)) }{1-2z T(z)}
\\ = z\frac{T(z)^2-2zT(z)^3+2z T(z)^3}{(1-2z T(z))^2}
\\ = z\frac{T(z)^2}{(1-2z T(z))^2}.$$

To extract  coefficients from  this we use  Lagrange inversion  in the
integral
$$[z^n] G(z)
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
z\frac{T(z)^2}{(1-2z T(z))^2} \; dz.$$

Put $w=T(z)$ so that $w = 1 + z w^2$ or
$$z = \frac{w-1}{w^2}
\quad\text{and}\quad
dz = \left(\frac{1}{w^2}-2\frac{w-1}{w^3}\right) \; dw.$$

This gives for the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{w^{2n}}{(w-1)^n} 
\frac{w^2}{(1-2(w-1)/w)^2}
\left(\frac{1}{w^2}-2\frac{w-1}{w^3}\right) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{w^{2n}}{(w-1)^n} 
\frac{w^4}{(w-2(w-1))^2}
\left(\frac{1}{w^2}-2\frac{w-1}{w^3}\right) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{w^{2n}}{(w-1)^n} 
\frac{w^4}{(1-(w-1))^2}
\frac{1-(w-1)}{w^3} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{w^{2n+1}}{(w-1)^n} 
\frac{1}{1-(w-1)}\; dw.$$

Expanding into a series we have
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^n} 
\sum_{q=0}^{2n+1} {2n+1\choose q} (w-1)^q
\sum_{p=0}^\infty (w-1)^p
\; dw$$

which yields
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n+1\choose q}
= -{2n+1\choose n}
+ \sum_{q=0}^{n} {2n+1\choose q}
= -{2n+1\choose n} + 2^{2n}.$$

This gives the sequence
$$1, 6, 29, 130, 562, 2380, 9949, 41226, 169766,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A008549](https://oeis.org/A008549)
where we learn of additional combinatorial interpretations.

For the average we get
$$-\frac{1}{n} C_n^{-1} {2n+1\choose n}
+ \frac{1}{n} 2^{2n} C_n^{-1}.$$

The second term produces the dominant asymptotics while the first term
yields
$$-\frac{n+1}{n} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} \frac{(2n+1)!}{n!(n+1)!}
= -\frac{2n+1}{n} = -2 - \frac{1}{n}.$$

Now using the asymptotics of the Catalan numbers which are
$$C_n\sim \frac{4^n}{n^{3/2}\sqrt{\pi}}$$

we finally obtain for the average depth the value
$$\frac{1}{n} 2^{2n} \frac{n^{3/2}\sqrt{\pi}}{4^n}$$
which simplifies to
$$\sqrt{\pi n}.$$

**Addendum, average height of leaves.**

Note that the functional equation for binary trees classified by total
height of  the leaves  is (use the  fact that  a tree on  $n$ internal
nodes has $n+1$ leaves)
$$T(z, u) = 1 + u^2 z T(uz, u)^2.$$

As we are interested in the average we need to compute
$$G(z) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} T(z, u)\right|_{u=1}.$$

We differentiate the functional equation, getting
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} T(z, u)
=  2u z T(uz, u)^2
+ 2u^2 z T(z, u) \left(z\frac{\partial}{\partial z} T(z, u)
+ \frac{\partial}{\partial u} T(z, u)\right).$$

We set $u=1$ to obtain
$$G(z) = 2z T(z)^2 + 2z T(z) (zT'(z)+G(z))$$
which yields
$$G(z) = z\frac{2T(z)^2 + 2zT(z)T'(z)}{1-2zT(z)}.$$

Substituting in the formula for $T'(z)$ yields
$$G(z) = z\frac{2T(z)^2 + 2zT(z)^3/(1-2zT(z))}{1-2zT(z)}
\\ = z\frac{2T(z)^2 -4zT(z)^3 + 2zT(z)^3}{(1-2zT(z))^2}
\\ = z\frac{2T(z)^2 - 2zT(z)^3}{(1-2zT(z))^2}
\\ = 2z T(z)^2\frac{1 - zT(z)}{(1-2zT(z))^2}.$$

This time the Lagrange inversion integral is
$$[z^n] G(z)
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
2z T(z)^2\frac{1 - zT(z)}{(1-2zT(z))^2}
\; dz.$$

Use the same substitution as before to obtain
for the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{2w^{2n}}{(w-1)^n} 
w^2 \frac{1-(w-1)/w}{(1-2(w-1)/w)^2}
\left(\frac{1}{w^2}-2\frac{w-1}{w^3}\right) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{2w^{2n}}{(w-1)^n} 
w \frac{1}{(1-2(w-1)/w)^2}
\frac{1-(w-1)}{w^3} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{2w^{2n}}{(w-1)^n} 
\frac{1}{(1-(w-1))^2}
(1-(w-1)) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{2w^{2n}}{(w-1)^n} 
\frac{1}{1-(w-1)} \; dw.$$

Re-write this to prepare for coefficient extraction:
$$\frac{2}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^n} \sum_{q=0}^{2n} {2n\choose q} (w-1)^q
\sum_{p=0}^\infty (w-1)^p \; dw.$$

This gives
$$2\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose q}
= 2^{2n} - {2n\choose n}.$$

This is the sequence
$$0, 2, 10, 44, 186, 772, 3172, 12952, 52666, 213524,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A068551](https://oeis.org/A068551).

For the asymptotics of the lower order term we get
$$-\frac{1}{n}{2n\choose n} C_n^{-1}
= -\frac{n+1}{n} = -1 - \frac{1}{n}.$$

For the dominant term we get the same as before
$$\frac{1}{n} 2^{2n} \frac{n^{3/2}\sqrt{\pi}}{4^n}$$
which simplifies to
$$\sqrt{\pi n}.$$

**Concrete verification.**
These data can be verified with the **combstruct** package (Maple).
This is the code.

```
with(combstruct);

gf :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local trees, leaves;

    trees := { T=Union(V, Prod(Z, Sequence(T, card=2))),
               Z=Atom, V=Atom };

    leaves :=
    proc(struct, height)
        if type(struct, function) then
            if op(0, struct) = Sequence then
                return add(leaves(op(q, struct), height+1),
                           q=1..nops(struct));
            else
                return add(leaves(op(q, struct), height),
                           q=1..nops(struct));
            fi;
        fi;

        if struct = Z then return 0 fi;
        return height;
    end;

    add(u^leaves(t, 0), t in allstructs([T, trees], size=2*n+1));
end;

f := n -> subs(u=1, diff(gf(n), u));
```

The output is

```
> seq(f(n), n=1..8);
              2, 10, 44, 186, 772, 3172, 12952, 52666
```

which confirms the data from above.

A slightly different approach may be consulted at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287877/).

Answer (score 0):

What is written is not quite correct.

First off, you need to assume something like your tree is binary, because if it is a star graph, all vertices, except the root, have degree 1.

Now the idea of the argument is, given a binary tree, [balance it out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).  This means move the leaves of the tree higher up until one gets a tree of some minimal height, call it $h$.  (In the OP, $h$ is overused, and cannot mean both the initial height and the height after doing this process--e.g., think of a path graph (i.e., a tree with only one vertex at each depth).)  This process will only lower the average depth of the tree, and as in the link, now $h$ is within one of $\log_2(n)$.