# Show that the average depth of a leaf in a binary tree with n vertices is Omega(lgn)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

I'm showing like this. 
The depth of a tree would be at least lgn. Let C be the number of leaves. 
Therefore, Omega(lgn). 
Please tell me, Am I right ?

Answer (score 4):

We start with the two functional equations

$$T(z) = z + z T^2(z)$$

and $$Q(z, u, v) = vz + z Q^2(z, u, uv)$$

where the first one is for binary  trees and the second one for binary
trees with the depth  marked where we set the depth of  the root to be
zero. The  variable $v$ marks leaves  and $u$ counts the  total depth.
We need to extract coefficients from $T(z)$ for the probabilities.  We
will do this  even though the answer is known,  because we will re-use
the computation later on.

We obtain

$$[z^n] T(z) =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} T(z) \; dz.$$

Using  the  functional  equation we  put  $T(z)  =  w$  so that

$$z  = \frac{w}{1+w^2}
\quad\text{and}\quad dz = (1-w^2)/(1+w^2)^2 \; dw.$$

and we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w^2)^{n+1}}{w^{n+1}} w
\frac{1-w^2}{(1+w^2)^2}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w^2)^{n-1}}{w^{n}}
(1-w^2)\; dw.$$

Extracting coefficients  we get zero for  $n$ even, one for  $n=1$ and
for $n$ odd, $n\ge 3,$

$${n-1\choose (n-1)/2} - {n-1\choose (n-3)/2}
\\ = {n-1\choose (n-1)/2} - {n-1\choose (n-1)/2}
\frac{(n-1)/2}{(n+1)/2}
= \frac{1}{(n+1)/2} {n-1\choose (n-1)/2}.$$

Now  for the  average depth  we require  (yes the  derivative is  with
respect to $u$)

$$A(z) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} Q(z,u,v)\right|_{u=1, v=1}.$$

Therefore we require

$$B(z) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} Q(z,u,v)\right|_{u=1, v=1}.$$

We have from the functional equation

$$B(z) = z + 2z T(z) B(z)$$ so that

$$B(z) = \frac{z}{1 - 2 z T(z)}.$$

Returning to $A(z)$ the functional equation yields

$$A(z) = 2z T(z) (A(z) + B(z))$$

or

$$A(z) = \frac{2z T(z) B(z)}{1 - 2 z T(z)}
= \frac{2z^2 T(z)}{(1 - 2 z T(z))^2}.$$

The coefficient extraction integral becomes

$$[z^n] A(z) =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{2z^2 T(z)}{(1 - 2 z T(z))^2}
\; dz.$$

Using the same substitution as before we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w^2)^{n+1}}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{2w^3/(1+w^2)^2}{(1 - 2 w^2/(1+w^2))^2}
\frac{1-w^2}{(1+w^2)^2}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w^2)^{n-1}}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{2w^3}{(1 - w^2)^2}
(1-w^2)
\; dw
\\ = \frac{2}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w^2)^{n-1}}{w^{n-2}}
\frac{1}{1 - w^2}
\; dw.$$

This vanishes for $n=1$, is zero for $n$ even and for $n$ odd has the value

$$2\sum_{q=0}^{(n-3)/2} {n-1\choose q}.$$

Putting $n=2m+3$ we get

$$2\sum_{q=0}^{m} {2m+2\choose q}
= 2\times \frac{1}{2} \times \left(2^{2m+2} - {2m+2\choose m+1}\right)
= 2^{n-1} - {n-1\choose (n-1)/2}.$$

Recall that  a binary  tree on  $n$ nodes with  $n$ odd  has $(n+1)/2$
leaves, as  can be seen by  a simple induction argument.  This finally
yields for the average depth

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)/2} 
\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)/2} {n-1\choose (n-1)/2}\right)^{-1}
\times \left(2^{n-1} - {n-1\choose (n-1)/2}\right)
\\ = {n-1\choose (n-1)/2}^{-1}
\times \left(2^{n-1} - {n-1\choose (n-1)/2}\right)
\\ = - 1 + 2^{n-1} \times {n-1\choose (n-1)/2}^{-1} .$$

We   have    from   the   [asymptotic   of    the   central   binomial
coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)

$${n-1\choose (n-1)/2} = {2((n-1)/2)\choose (n-1)/2}
\sim \frac{4^{(n-1)/2}}{\sqrt{\pi (n-1)/2}}$$

Therefore the average depth is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
-1+\sqrt{\pi (n-1)/2}.}$$

**Remarks.** The sequences  for the total count  (Catalan numbers) and
the      total     depth      can      be      found     at      [OEIS
A000108](http://oeis.org/A000108)               and              [OEIS
A068551](http://oeis.org/A068551).  A Maple  script  to compute  these
from the functional equation goes like this:

```
CF :=
proc(k)
option remember;
    if k = 0 then return 0 end if;
    if k = 1 then return v end if;
    expand(subs(v = u*v, add(CF(q)*CF(k - 1 - q), q = 1 .. k - 1)))
end proc;


AVG := n-> subs([u=1, v=1], diff(CF(n), u))/
subs([u=1, v=1], CF(n))/((n+1)/2);

AVG2 := n -> -1 + sqrt(1/2 *Pi* (n - 1));
```

There is also a Perl script to compute them by total enumeration.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

my @trees = (-1, [[]]);

sub btrees {
    my ($n) = @_;

    return $trees[$n] 
        if $n < scalar(@trees);

    my @res;

    for(my $k=1; $k<$n-1; $k++){
        foreach my $left (@{ btrees($k) }){
            foreach my $right (@{ btrees($n-1-$k) }){
                push @res, [$left, $right];
            }
        }
    }

    $trees[$n] = \@res;
    return $trees[$n];
}

sub treedepths {
    my ($tree, $tref, $depth) = @_;

    if(scalar(@$tree) == 0){
        $$tref += $depth;
        return;
    }

    treedepths($tree->[0], $tref, $depth+1);
    treedepths($tree->[1], $tref, $depth+1);
}

sub alldepths {
    my ($n) = @_;

    my $res = 0;
    foreach my $tree (@{ btrees($n) }){
        treedepths($tree, \$res, 0);
    }

    return $res;
}

 MAIN: {
     my $mx = int(shift || 7);

     for(my $n=1; $n <= $mx; $n++){
         my $count = scalar(@{ btrees($n) });
         my $depths = alldepths($n);

         print "$n: $count $depths\n";
     }

     1;
}
```

The result is a table that runs as follows:

```
1: 1 0
2: 0 0
3: 1 2
4: 0 0
5: 2 10
6: 0 0
7: 5 44
8: 0 0
9: 14 186
10: 0 0
11: 42 772
12: 0 0
13: 132 3172
14: 0 0
15: 429 12952
```

This can be extended to about $27$ nodes even though the script is not
optimized.

This was also computed using a slightly different approach at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287877/).

Comment: Seems gigantic. 

Comment: It frequently happens that a different user will post an easy proof once a result has been established. It seems a bonus with this problem that we can establish the first term of the asymptotics with a reasonable amount of computation.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your kind help. This solution is out my scope. But I've tried it using h>=lgl where l represents leaves. => h>=lg(n+1)-1>=lgn. So h=Omega(lgn). Am I correct?

Comment: Instructive solution! (+1)